# how to select the dataframe from user input

Tags: python

I'm new to python and want to def a function that does this:

```py
def VAR():
  teamA = input('Choose your team A: ')
  teamB = input('Choose your team B: ')
  league= input('Choose your league: ')
```

I have this idea:

```py
if teamA and teamB in league.values:
```

And I have different dataframes, so for example: if I want to choose NBA so I put NBA and it runs:

```py
if teamA and teamB in NBA.values:
```

But it's not working because when I use `input` it changes the type to a string. How can I fix this?

Comment: `if (teamA in league.values) and (teamB in league.values):`

Comment: yeah that should work but the problem is when you use league=input(), because it appears league is a str and it doesnt have values.

Comment: If you store your dataframes in dictionaries, then you can use the string dictionary key to select the dataframe stored as the value for that key

Comment: Is the dataframe you are using a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @DanielAguirre. Ah:
`import sys`
`thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]` `getattr(thismodule, league)`

Comment: yes, for example: NBA and Baseball dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

> league is a str and it doesnt have values

You can use strings to lookup a dictionary which has values

```
teams = leagues[league].values()
if teamA in teams and teamB in teams:
    # both are there
```

The problem with the syntax of

```
if teamA and teamB in X
```

is that it is calcuated as this, which is not what you want

```
if (teamA) and (teamB in X)
```

---

If you are using pandas, then using a `where`/`filter` function would make more sense